# ReCaptcha integration with a VisualForce page and Custom Controller

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF registration form with the new google recaptcha widget on it. When a user populates the needed info on the form, and goes successfully through reCaptcha, upon clicking the submit button, we check the validation and return the problems to the page (ex: "please enter correct zip code"). However, since the page doesn't reload, when the user enters correct info and goes to submit again (without having to do the recaptcha again)...the recaptcha is no longer valid and they can't submit without reloading the page.

is there a good solution to this? Can I reload the widget somehow? I tried utilizing grecaptcha.reset(); but not sure if I am doing it correctly or not. I did read through other forums and the proposed Java solutions, but really not sure how that fits in within VF. Could someone give me guidance please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the corresponding code also.

Comment: Thank you for responding Reshma.
Here is an example I got from google and I am assuming I have to use explicit:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api
The issue I have is how to translate that into my VF page or Controller. I am not sure what would go where as I am quite new to Apex and Java.